# How to get Order using OrderConfirmationId/TrackingNumber in Sitecore Commerce?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I need to get Order detail using OrderConfirmationId in sitecore commerce storefront side(not in commerce engine). I could only find methods in OrderServiceProvider which requires OrderId to get Order. Is there any api or method from where we can get order by OrderConfirmationId/TrackingNumber. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the normal GetVisitorOrder method from the OrderServiceProvider and pass the OrderConfirmationId into the OrderID. The engine API accepets both the orderid and orderconfirmationid as the key.

Comment: Thanks. It works with OrderConfirmationId also.